# Is it possible to eject a cd in a batch file on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, batch, compact-disc, eject

I've seen a few executables/utilities that do it, and many forums that say it is not possible to do. But is there any DOS command that I can rely on in a typical XP installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no way using rundll or a preexisting executable.

If you have windows scripting host installed, maybe the following helps (untested, copied from another forum)

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
colCDROMs.Item(0).Eject
```

Change the (0) if you have more than one drive.

Comment: FYI, every Windows has WSH installed (at least anything since 2k).

Answer (score 1):

I can do better than that...
Paste this into a batch file called "eject.bat":

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=6" %%i in (`vol %1:`) do if "" neq "%%i" rsm eject /pf%%i
```

You can pass any drive letter to this batch file, so you can eject any drive. You can even eject devices like iPods and USB drives.

Comment: Didn't work for me on my laptop's tray CD drive in XP.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it only works if there is a disk in the drive! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [windows API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165721) call to do it, but unfortunately not a built in command.

There is a [command line tool](http://www.technize.com/2008/07/11/four-ways-to-inserteject-cd-rom-tray-in-windows/) you can download though that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Executables do it using the [`mciSendCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709485(VS.85).aspx) API. I don't think it can be done though batch as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Necro. Nir Command shortcut option "nircmdc.exe cdrom open D:" where D is your optical drive. Change icon for shortcut to something appropriate to eject.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Batch file:

```
@echo off
echo CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7").CDRomCollection.Item(0).Eject() >temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs
del temp.vbs
```