# Is there an RSM replacement in Windows 7? (to eject USB and Firewire devices from command line)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, usb, eject

I know Windows XP and previous had an `rsm.exe` file in the `<root>\windows\system32` folder that could be used to manage media. I used this command in batch files and from the command line to eject external disks (iPod, CF cardreader, etc.).

This utility appears not to be included in Windows 7, and I wonder if there is some replacement utility that will allow the same thing. I've been unable to find any such thing.

*I'm aware of the 3rd party utilities; this question is only about what is included with Windows 7.*

Comment: Copy rsm.exe from an earlier version of windows onto 7?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [USB Disk Ejector](http://quickandeasysoftware.net/software/usb-disk-ejector) in the past, for a backup-to-USB script I made ages ago.

Using a few of the adjectives used on their website, the reasons I liked it was: It is quick, simple, small and open source - and it can be run from command line.

You can unmount a drive simply by running:

```
USB_Disk_Eject.exe /removeletter X:
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Windows Scripting. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/42605/is-it-possible-to-eject-a-cd-in-a-batch-file-on-windows-xp/42612#42612). Caveat, I haven't tried it in 7.

Comment: Thank you... this seems to apply only to optical media drives, as it uses Windows Media Player.

Comment: Guess I didn't fully read your question and that answer at the same time. My answer (using rsm.exe in a batch file) to that question can eject USB/iPod etc. but was "not as good" as the accepted answer, so I assumed the accepted answer would be better for you as well. Now I'm curious to see if this can be done in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool:
http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html

This one can give you %errorlevel% in a batch file, in case you need it.