# Eject CD-ROM drive from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I have a Dell laptop using Windows 7 and am trying to write a script for Autohotkey to eject the CD-ROM drive but so far, no luck.  Can someone help please.
Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there some reason this has to be an autohotkey script? There may be easier ways of accomplishing what you're trying to do - what's the actual goal here?

Comment: If AutoHotKey supports doing Batch scripts, then you might [find this previous question from SU to be of some help](http://superuser.com/questions/42605/is-it-possible-to-eject-a-cd-in-a-batch-file-on-windows-xp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Drive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Drive.htm) command to eject an optical drive.

- To eject the default drive:

  ```
  Drive, Eject
  ```
- To eject a specific drive, use its drive letter (e.g. `D:`):

  ```
  Drive, Eject, D:
  ```

Comment: Drive, Eject, D: worked just fine.  Many thanks.  I wish I knew how to award points on here.

Comment: @Carlos, you can award points by clicking the **upvote** ▲ symbol and by **accepting** ✔ an answer. See this FAQ regarding accepting answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/172108